# Can Firefox Inspect Element Network find json strings like Chrome can?

Tags: json, google-chrome, firefox, web-inspector

My intention is to analyze json strings as part of REST messages.
In Chrome there are possibilities to use *Inspect* -> tab *Network* to find the json string that I want. However I cannot find the json string in Firefox.
Does Firefox support this?

I will show an example from a public page.

1. Open https://www.theguardian.com/ in Chrome
2. Inspect (Ctrl-Shift-I) and select tab Network
3. Click UK (UK News)

On tab *Response* you will find json strings as for examlple comment-counts.json
like

```
{"counts":[
  {"id":"/p/5kmed","count":269},{"id":"/p/5kkv8","count":39},
  {"id":"/p/5kq4t","count":5},{"id":"/p/5k7x7","count":1064},
  {"id":"/p/5ky88","count":1720},{"id":"/p/5kp8e","count":841},
  {"id":"/p/5kkbv","count":692}]
}"
```

[Image: Inspecting The Guardian UK News](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EC3gP.png)

In Firefox I cannot get this piece of code. I have tried *Inspect Element* tab *Network* and sub-tabs *Headers, Params* and *Response*.
Do anyone know if it is possible in Firefox and in that case how to get it?

Background: I'm working in a corporate linux system where I haven't authority to install so much. However I have access to Firefox 45.5.1 and a bad build of Chrome 43.0.2357.81.

Thanks for any idea you come up with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, Firefox currently offers only a "structured view" of JSON responses in the developer tools.

[image]

There is a [ticket in Bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=859138) requesting plain text view.
Not sure about Firefox 45, but the latest release offers a context menu entry which allows copying response text to clipboard. Maybe that helps.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. You helped me, but I am not allowed to flag your answer up as I'm a newbie.

Answer (score 0):

With Rafael's answer I found out what I needed.
Sometimes *Copy Response* works fine.
When that does not work I can find what I need from *Copy All As HAR*, which contains more or less everything before "now".

Since I'm a newbie I can neither flag up Rafaels answer nor flag that this question has been answered.
From my perspective I am fully satisfied and the case can be closed.